# udev Rule Doesn't Trigger When USB Gamepad Connected

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, udev, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 hooked up to my TV. When I plug in my USB controller, I would like to run a script that uses CEC to turn on my TV, switches the TV input to the Pi, then starts Steam Link. The script works if I run it myself, but I can't seem to get the rule to trigger when the controller is plugged in. And yes, I did `sudo udevadm control --reload`

Here is my working script, saved as `/usr/local/bin/autogame.sh`

```
echo 'on 0.0.0.0' | cec-client -s -d 1
echo 'as' | cec-client -s -d 1
/usr/bin/steamlink
```

This is the result of running `udevadm monitor --kernel --property --subsystem-match=usb` and plugging in the controller

```
monitor will print the received events for:
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[189783.367795] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/012
DEVTYPE=usb_device
PRODUCT=e6f/213/100
TYPE=255/255/255
BUSNUM=001
DEVNUM=012
SEQNUM=1838
MAJOR=189
MINOR=11

KERNEL[189783.373779] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
PRODUCT=e6f/213/100
TYPE=255/255/255
INTERFACE=255/93/1
MODALIAS=usb:v0E6Fp0213d0100dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip01in00
SEQNUM=1839

KERNEL[189783.374744] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=bind
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
DRIVER=xpad
PRODUCT=e6f/213/100
TYPE=255/255/255
INTERFACE=255/93/1
MODALIAS=usb:v0E6Fp0213d0100dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip01in00
SEQNUM=1844

KERNEL[189783.375136] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
PRODUCT=e6f/213/100
TYPE=255/255/255
INTERFACE=255/93/3
MODALIAS=usb:v0E6Fp0213d0100dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip03in01
SEQNUM=1845

KERNEL[189783.375580] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
PRODUCT=e6f/213/100
TYPE=255/255/255
INTERFACE=255/93/2
MODALIAS=usb:v0E6Fp0213d0100dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc5Dip02in02
SEQNUM=1846

KERNEL[189783.384551] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.3 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.3
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
PRODUCT=e6f/213/100
TYPE=255/255/255
INTERFACE=255/253/19
MODALIAS=usb:v0E6Fp0213d0100dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFiscFDip13in03
SEQNUM=1847

KERNEL[189783.385026] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2 (usb)
ACTION=bind
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/012
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
PRODUCT=e6f/213/100
TYPE=255/255/255
BUSNUM=001
DEVNUM=012
SEQNUM=1848
MAJOR=189
MINOR=11
```

This is what I get from `udevadm info -ap /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2`

```
  looking at device '//devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2':
    KERNEL=="1-1.2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
    DRIVER=="usb"
    ATTR{bDeviceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTR{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTR{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTR{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTR{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTR{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTR{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="ff"
    ATTR{urbnum}=="34"
    ATTR{idVendor}=="0e6f"
    ATTR{speed}=="12"
    ATTR{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTR{devspec}=="  (null)"
    ATTR{devnum}=="17"
    ATTR{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTR{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTR{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{serial}=="05F89012"
    ATTR{devpath}=="1.2"
    ATTR{authorized}=="1"
    ATTR{busnum}=="1"
    ATTR{manufacturer}=="Performance Designed Products"
    ATTR{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTR{product}=="Afterglow Gamepad for Xbox 360"
    ATTR{idProduct}=="0213"
    ATTR{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTR{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTR{configuration}==""
    ATTR{bDeviceProtocol}=="ff"
```

And these are the rules I've tried with no success, saved as `/etc/udev/rules.d/00-usb-autogame.rules`.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{PRODUCT}=="e6f/213/100", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/autogame.sh"
```

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", PRODUCT=="e6f/213/100", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/autogame.sh"
```

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{serial}=="05F89012", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/autogame.sh"
```

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="Afterglow Gamepad for Xbox 360", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/autogame.sh"
```

Comment: udev rules cannot run long tasks such as steamlink. You'll need to use [systemd service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631550/31463) and something like [xpub](https://github.com/Ventto/xpub) for getting X/Wayland screen information for launching steamlink