# Use systemd to run script when usb drive is unmounted

Tags: systemd, mount, udev, fstab, unmounting

I have a systemd service that calls a script when a USB drive is mounted. `signal.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description= Updater trigger
Requires=usb-drive.mount
After=usb-drive.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/signal

[Install]
WantedBy=usb-drive.mount
```

Which results in proper order. `Journalctl`:

```
systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/usb...
systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/usb.
systemd[1]: usb-drive.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: signal.service: Succeeded.
```

Now, I want to run a script (remove mounting point folder) when the user pulls the USB drive out and the system unmounts the drive.
I created udev rule:

```
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="7-1.1",SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/removeFolder.sh"
```

The problem is that the script sometimes is called after the drive is unmounted and sometimes before.
How can I make sure the script is called after:

```
systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/usb.
```

Or how can I use systemd to run the script when the system unmounted the drive?

My goal is to remove /mnt/usb folder on unmount. Maybe I don't need systemd or udev rules, maybe adding extra rule to /etc/fstab could make it?
Currently, I have the following rule:

```
/dev/sda1        /mnt/usb    auto     nofail,rw     0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information on [This blogpost](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2014/01/20/udev/)

Basicly the man page of udev advises against using RUN+= for longer processes, and in a [Archlinux forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149419) they came up with a solution for using SYSTEMD_WANTS so that you would have a systemd unit for the script that you want to run and call it from the udev rule.

You would need something like this:
A systemd service that calls the script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Delete /mnt/usb folder on unmount
Requires=usb-drive.mount
After=usb-drive.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/removeFolder.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=usb-drive.mount
```

Your udev rule:

```
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="7-1.1",SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}=="removefolder.service"
```

As you said, maybe it makes more sense to do it from the first systemd service.

Comment: The problem with the udev rule I proposed is that it is called on remove event which happens before /mnt/usb gets unmounted. It is not a problem with RUN script. So I guess I would have to completely get rid of udev rule and replace it with systemd service, but I don't know what would have to be ```After``` for the service to be called after /mnt/usb unmounted.